# streaming file with FFmpeg won't start on the specific time with -ss

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, rtmps

Hi I'm trying to stream a file to Facebook but I would like to start the streaming in 00:01:21 of the video whit the command

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:20 \
-re -i 'My_Video.mp4' -f pulse -ac 2 \
-i default -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 \
-preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 \
-threads 0 -bufsize 1000k -vb 500k -maxrate 500k -deinterlace -g 30 -r 30\
-f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize "rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/MY_FACEBOOK_KEY"
```

but the stream do not start in the 00:01:20 just start regularly in the 00:00:00.00, what could be wrong ? thank you all for your time !

my ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: Any particular reason why you cannot prepare a trimmed version of `My_Video.mp4`? Only other thing I see is to remove `-re` which does nothing but harm (don't know if it affects your issue tho)

Comment: I was trying to skip rendering,  try to use as a raw file and whit a script jump between cues, but yes I think about the solution is trim the videos any ways I may clear some space in that way thank you

Comment: You deleted your question about a MySQL query with PHP variables and you made some remarks about how unpleasant our comments were for you. Sorry, that was never our intention. If you read the comments again you'll see that we never made it personal. All we asked was that you tell us what the variables contain, because that was the cause of the error message. You never told us. According to you the question was already very good. We also advised strongly to use prepared statements, instead of inserting PHP variables into the query string or "cleaning" the variables. That is sound advice.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank you for reaching, I don't say it was a really good question in fact if I post something I hope some one tell me in what I'm wrong since I'm looking for it because I don't figure out, I just mean there was not need to qualify negatively just cause its a duplicate question whit some advise like hey go here, do this more like a guide instead an a judge, I don't know if was you who qualify negative, but in fact yes I did found the answer thanks to my question but get negative from people, this is supposedly to help people not judge them :(

Comment: You mistake a judgement of the question for a judgement of you personally. It is not. Although I agree we should always aim to be courteous, SO is a site about how code can be improved. That is a brutal sport. I am a scientist. One of the objectives of science is to attack someone else's work, ruthlessly, and to get your work attacked. I consider it a honor if I get criticized. It means someone thinks my work is worthy of it. They are willing to invest the time. Try to view comment and votes in a more positive light, and remember SO doesn't only serve you, it is intended for all its readers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sorry I don't share you point of view, I believe in the scientist way but its the firths time some one say to me something like science is to attack someone else's work I don't share that, you may be in disagreed in some one else work and do it in your way to prove the correct way to do so but even if you are right that doesn't allow you to attack any ones work,  if you judge someone else work yes you are judging there self because they work its a reflect of what they are, and yes I know this is for everyone and not for some elite group

Comment: and I know its not to serve me I think on it more like help me and help others